# How to set state of one function component from another function component in react

Tags: reactjs, react-native, use-state

I have two sibling function components. I am using useState hook to set the state in both components but I want to update the state of one component on click of button in another component.

Comment: You don't - if they need to share state, lift it up to their parent.

Comment: Actually I have separate search component and list component ,so on click of search i have to update th list component data

Answer (score 0):

Pass a function to all Components that are you render on FlatList or .map.

Not is the best way but this is an example:

[image: example]